Is All Descendants Always Rerendered
I am reading the React new documentation here, it said:

Here, the context value is a JavaScript object with two properties,
one of which is a function. Whenever MyApp re-renders (for example, on
a route update), this will be a different object pointing at a
different function, so React will also have to re-render all
components deep in the tree that call useContext(AuthContext).

For what said "so React will also have to re-render all components deep in the tree that call useContext(AuthContext)", I wonder is that not so right. From what I tested, as long as a parent component call setState() method, the parent component along with all its children and children's children, actually all descendants, is being rerendered.
The "have to rerender components deep in the tree that call useContext" seems not right to me, whether a descendant calling a useContext or not, it is going to be rerendered. Is my understanding right or not?

Your understanding is correct, but it's just an understanding of the default behavior. You are correct that, if you take no steps to prevent it, rendering a component will cause all its descendants to be rerendered too, regardless of whether they call useContext.
But for performance reasons you will sometimes want to skip rendering components if nothing has changed. This is typically done by wrapping a component in React.memo. When a memoized component is going to render, it first compares its previous and next props. If they have not changed, it will skip rendering, and reuse the virtual dom from the previous render. This in turn will cause the entire subtree below it to skip rendering as well.
Context will pierce through these layers of memoization. So you can have a grandparent component A, which renders an <AuthContext.Provider>, then a parent component B which is memoized and takes no props, then a child component C which calls useContext(AuthContext). If A sets state and passes a new value into the provider, B skips rendering because none of its props have changed, and C renders because the context has changed.

That is a good clarification, very clear, thanks Nicholas.

It doesn't even have to use React.memo. Rendering an element created from useMemo, or even just rendering children that are passed as a prop (with the same value as before) work as well.
